# VBA: using data on one sheet to target another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel to create a tool that will help me DM a D&D campaign, and am currently working on a spellcasting system. My goal is to be able to click a button on one worksheet ("Combat") which will decrement a spell slot (numerical value) in a different worksheet (the name of the target worksheet being derived from a text value in the "Combat" worksheet), corresponding to a given spell level. These values are referenced by cells in the "Combat" sheet, which will change with the values of the cells in the other sheet.
The code I have is:

```
Private Sub CastSpell_Click()
    SpellAction "CastSpell"
End Sub


Sub SpellAction(ByVal action As String)
    Dim Combat As Worksheet
    Set Combat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combat")
    Dim Player As Worksheet
    Set Player = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Cells(5, 12).Text)

    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = Player.Range("Z31", "Z39").Find(Left(Combat.Cells(18, 12).Text, 3))

    If Not (foundCell Is Nothing) Then
        r = foundCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the current selection."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case LCase(action)
        Case "CastSpell"
            If Not (Player.Cells(r, 28) = 0) Then
                Cells(r, 28) = Cells(r, 28) - 1
            Else
                MsgBox "No remaining spell slots of this level."
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Where
`Cells(5, 12)` refers to a text string picked from a dropdown list, `Range("Z31", "Z39")` refers to a column containing values (1) through (9), `Cells(18, 12)` refers to the name of the spell, (example: (1) Cure Wounds), and the number 28 referenced in `Cells(r, 28)` refers to column AB, which is the column of the cell whose value I wish to decrement.

Currently, when I click the button (named "CastSpell" and located in the "Combat" sheet), it runs through the `SpellAction` code, finding the correct values for `Player`, `foundCell`, and `r` without an error message, but does not execute the code within `"CastSpell"`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declaring ranges is done as "Z31:Z39". Currently you're only referring z31 & z39, not all of the cells in between. The comma is how you include multiple ranges out of sequence. This however might not be the reason why its failing, its worth pointing out that you're missing out on most of your selection.. It also looks like you're using select case on a lower case string but then check for a string which has upper case letters, which is most likely why its failing as you're converting a string to "xxxxx"  but checking for "XxxxxXxx." Either convert it and then check for the lower case version of the string, or dont bother converting at all.

Does that help?